# верстка table и border-radius

Tags: html, css, html5

Не удается задать `border-radius` к `thead tr` прошу помощи.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmqqycv8/)

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table .table-hover {
  padding: 0;
  width: 7px;
}

thead tr {
  transition: linear 1s;
  background-color: rgb(255, 223, 0);
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.bold-paragraph {
  min-width: 290px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.364;
}

.table td,
.table th,
.table thead th {
  border: none;
}

tr:hover th {
  background: rgb(255, 223, 0);
}

tr:hover td {
  background: #fffce5
}

.table {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 13px 30px 0px rgba(28, 33, 36, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="table-hover"></th>
      <th scope="col">
        <p class="bold-paragraph">1</p>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <p class="bold-paragraph">2</p>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <p class="bold-paragraph">3</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="table-hover"></th>
      <td>
        <p class="light-bold-paragraph">1</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>2</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>3</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="table-hover"></th>
      <td>
        <p class="light-bold-paragraph">1</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>2</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>3</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ни как у меня не получается сделать

[image: Как у меня не получается сделать]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table {
      text-align: center;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .table .table-hover {
      padding: 0;
      width: 7px;
    }

    thead tr {
      transition: linear 1s;
      background-color: rgb(255, 223, 0);
      border: 3px solid #fff;
    }

    .bold-paragraph {
      min-width: 290px;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-family: "Fira Sans";
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 1.364;
    }

    .table td,
    .table th,
    .table thead th {
      border: none;
    }

    tr:hover th {
      background: rgb(255, 223, 0);
    }

    tr:hover td {
      background: #fffce5
    }

    .table {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      box-shadow: 0px 13px 30px 0px rgba(28, 33, 36, 0.25);
    }

    thead th:first-of-type {
      background: none;
    }

    thead th:nth-child(2) {
      border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }

    thead th:last-of-type {
      border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    }
```

```html
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" class="table-hover"></th>
    <th scope="col">
      <p class="bold-paragraph">1</p>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <p class="bold-paragraph">2</p>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <p class="bold-paragraph">3</p>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" class="table-hover"></th>
    <td>
      <p class="light-bold-paragraph">1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" class="table-hover"></th>
    <td>
      <p class="light-bold-paragraph">1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```